# why ionic bundle js file is not present in project?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have created a new project using CLI, it works fine and no error came in. But I was reading the documentation [getting started](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/starting.html) where I see there is a library folder from where css and js file is being loaded. But In my case I cant see any library folder . Do I have to add it by myself or is there a problem in creating new project or with `ionic serve`. For better Understanding I am adding the screen shot of my directory.
[image]

I have ionic **cli** 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you created an ionic version 3 project. Judging from the documentation, you want ionic v1.x.

Do:

```
ionic start myproj blank --type ionic1
```

Comment: nothing wrong.. it is vastly different from  1 . The docs are http://ionicframework.com/docs/. You need to know typescript and angular 2 +